# Old favicon still showing for a split second during redirection

Tags: bug, status-declined, favicon

When I click my bookmark which points to `stackoverflow.com`, the old favicon shows for a split second (seemingly while it redirects to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/...`), causing the browser to save the old favicon in my bookmark bar.

See below for an example of what's happening for me. You can see under my cursor that the old favicon is still being saved in my bookmark.

[image]

Untested in anything but Chrome on Windows 7. Maybe this is a chrome bug, I'm not sure. When I deleted and re-created a bookmark to `stackoverflow.com` this kept happening.

Comment: I'm not seeing the same behavior on Chrome/Linux.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: @Cerbrus cleared my cache and restarted chrome, same behavior.

Comment: Maybe [this will help](http://superuser.com/questions/375321/how-to-refresh-bookmark-favicons-in-chrome)?

Comment: The way browsers handle favicons are tricky. It has nothing to do with StackOverflow, but the way your browser saves, and doesn't refresh your icons. A favorite site of mine has changed favicons months ago, and every time I reboot my PC, the bookmark still shows the old one. As soon as I visit it, the bookmark shows the new one, until I repeat the process.

Answer (score 7):

That is not an actual redirect you're seeing, it's the newnav prototype replacing the url with the permalink via `history.replaceState(...)`. Since this happens very quickly - I can only guess before chrome has time to fetch and save the new favicon for the `http://stackoverflow.com` url - the old favicon never get's replaced.

All the favicons are correctly changed, the url has a new cachebreaker. This bug is definitely in Chrome.

Deleting the `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Favicons` file (as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/376292/63967))  did the trick for me. You could also disable newnav, go to the homepage to force the refresh, and than enable it back again.